# How can I set the Background of all my activities in styles.xml

Tags: android, background, styles

I am trying to customize my styles.xml file to display the same background for each one of my activities.

I tried this code in my styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/mybg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

this worked pretty well untill I put a TextView in my activity.. Every View I put in my layout get the same background, and that is really annoying

What is the best practice to set only the background of the activity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I have found my answer:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">
```

fits all my needs

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="yourstylename">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mybg</item>
</style>
```

and set this style to all your activities root element in xml file.